# Problems decoding using AES on C#

Tags: c#, aes, string-decoding

Hi Guys I have problem on decoding my text, When I want decode VS Debugger shows me "The input data is not a complete block."
I tried each way to fix this problem but i could not find :(
Could anybody help me?
Thanks.

```
        //Encoding
        try
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathread);
            aes.IV = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(textBox3.Text));
            aes.Key = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(textBox4.Text));
            aes.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;

            aes.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform ic2 = aes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] enc = ic2.TransformFinalBlock(utf8.GetBytes(str), 0, utf8.GetBytes(str).Length);
            richTextBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(enc);
            //string toraj = BitConverter.ToString(ic2.TransformFinalBlock(utf8.GetBytes(str), 0, utf8.GetBytes(str).Length));
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }



        //Decoding
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        string str =  richTextBox1.Text.ToString();

        aes.IV = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(textBox3.Text));
        aes.Key = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(textBox4.Text));
        aes.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
        MessageBox.Show(str);
        byte[] encrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        aes.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform ic5 = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        //for (int x = 0; x <= encrypted.Length; x++)
        //{
        //    Array.Reverse(encrypted);
        //}
        MessageBox.Show(encrypted[0].ToString("X"));

       MessageBox.Show( utf8.GetString(ic5.TransformFinalBlock(utf8.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text), 0, utf8.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text).Length)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(enc);
```

This is you writing the bytes to your textbox.

```
utf8.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text)
```

And this is how you get them out. Do you really think this will result in the same bytes? Take a debugger, and check both of your byte arrays when you have encrypted them and before you decrypt them. Then find a way to store your byte array without changing it. You could store it seperately *or* you could change your routine of writing it into the textbox *or* you could change your routine of reading it from the textbox. Pick the one you like best.

Comment: Thanks and i thought about it, so i should separate all of them with split  and add them into list or other thing? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Probably something simple like `var bytes = richTextBox1.Text.Split('-').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray()`.